# Manipular registros de uma array php

Tags: php

Possuo uma consulta no banco que me retorna os registros em uma array, gostaria de saber como faço para manipular estes registros, tira-los da array.

***Código***

```
$array = MinPDO::consult("intro", NULL, "id > 1", "id-", "3", "%e%");

var_dump($array);
```

***Registros***

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["param1"]=> string(5) "ele01" ["param2"]=> string(6) "param2" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["param1"]=> string(5) "ele01" ["param2"]=> string(6) "param2" } [2]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["param1"]=> string(5) "ele01" ["param2"]=> string(6) "param2" } }
```

Comment: Onde você quer manipular na view ou no próprio código php?

Comment: Para acessar alguma valor vc pode fazer `$array[0]['param1']`

Comment: Na view e no própio código também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pode usar o foreach para isso segue abaixo um exemplo

```
foreach($array as $info) {
    echo $info['id']." - ".$info['param2']."<br/>";
}
```

> Tem o for também porem o **foreach** é melhor

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo $array[$i]['id']." - ".$array[$i]['param2']."<br/>";
}
```